# MySQL SELECT for iterating through dates

Tags: php, mysql, iteration

I have this MySql table (simplified):

```
tbl_cards
ID  FROM        TO
--------------------------
 1  2015-10-01  2015-10-08
 2  2015-10-06  2015-10-12
 3  2015-10-06  2015-10-15
 4  ...
```

I need a SELECT which checks every date between e.g. 2015-10-01 and 2015-12-31 and returns the dates where 3 (or an arbitrary number) ID's overlap. Some dates won't have any records, while others may have a lot.

In the table above, 2015-10-06 and 2015-10-07 are "shared" by 3 records, which means that those are the dates I need returned:

```
Index  Date
-----------------
 0     2015-10-06
 1     2015-10-07
 2     2015-10-08
```

I can of course make my php script iterate every date in the specified span and count the records for each date, but I'm guessing it would be faster if the whole operation can be done inside MySql?

Comment: You may have to do it manually on PHP side... It would be hard to write in a query... You need date items and loops...

Comment: Imagine that the first row ran until the 8th. Presumably you would still want the 7th to show up in the results. So you need some way of generating 'missing' dates. Either use a calendar/utility/union table in MySQL or, better, handle the display logic in your application layer.

Comment: @Strawberry, that's correct. Bad example from my part. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> - create a calendar data source with some decimal logic ( all numbers expressed as an*10^n + ... a0*10^0 ) with `digits_v` and date_add around
>     numbers
> - join calender data to `tbl_cards` with condition falls in interval
> - aggregate over above having count equal to 3
> - use a variable to create index field output

---

**setup**

```
create table tbl_cards
(
  id integer primary key not null,
  `from` date not null,
  `to` date not null
);

insert into tbl_cards
( id, `from`, `to` )
values
( 1,  '2015-10-01',  '2015-10-08' ),
( 2,  '2015-10-06',  '2015-10-12' ),
( 3,  '2015-10-06',  '2015-10-15' )
;

drop view if exists digits_v;
create view digits_v
as
select 0 as n
union all
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all 
select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
;
```

**query**

```
select @index := @index + 1 as `Index`, `Date`
from
(
  select date_format(calendar.dy, '%Y-%m-%d') as `Date`
  from
  (
    select date_add(date('2015-10-01'), interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) as dy
    from digits_v a2
    cross join digits_v a1
    cross join digits_v a0
    where date_add('2015-10-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day) 
    <=    date('2015-12-31')
    order by date_add('2015-10-01', interval a2.n * 100 + a1.n * 10 + a0.n day)
  ) calendar
  inner join tbl_cards t
  on calendar.dy between t.`from` and t.`to`
  group by calendar.dy
  having count(calendar.dy) = 3
) dts
cross join ( select @index := -1 ) params
;
```

**output**

```
+-------+------------+
| Index |    Date    |
+-------+------------+
|     0 | 2015-10-06 |
|     1 | 2015-10-07 |
|     2 | 2015-10-08 |
+-------+------------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea43e/3)**

---

**reference**

- [creating mysql calendar table](https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables)

Comment: I'm taking off my hat for you. That's very impressive, and excactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no worries. you might also want to consider creating a complete calendar table ( for simplifying exactly these sorts of queries )

Comment: Yes, I read the same advice in some other posts. This will suffice for now :)