# Using union with nested selects and temporary tables

Tags: php, mysql, iteration, union

This is a follow-up question to the excellent answer given by @amdixon on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606195/mysql-select-for-iterating-through-dates/33606644?noredirect=1#comment54988621_33606644) the other day.

Quick summary: I had this MySql table (simplified):

```
tbl_cards
ID  FROM        TO
--------------------------
1  2015-10-01  2015-10-08
2  2015-10-06  2015-10-12
3  2015-10-06  2015-10-15
4  ...
```

I needed a SELECT which checked every date between e.g. 2015-10-01 and 2015-12-31 and returned the dates where 3 (or an arbitrary number of) ID's overlap. Some dates won't have any records, while others may have a lot.

@amdixon supplied me with this answer, which was excactly what I needed (mind you, there is also a mySql view called 'digits' involved. Have a look at the thread above)

```
select @index := @index + 1 as `Index`, `Date`
from
(
select date_format(calendar.dy, '%Y-%m-%d') as `Date`
from
(
select date_add(date('2015-10-01'), interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day) as dy
from digits a2
cross join digits a1
cross join digits a0
where date_add('2015-10-01', interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day) <= date('2015-12-31')
order by date_add('2015-10-01', interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day)
) calendar
inner join tbl_cards t
on calendar.dy between t.`from` and t.`to`
group by calendar.dy
having count(calendar.dy) = 3
) dts
cross join ( select @index := -1 ) params
;
```

For my follow-up question, it might be necessary to give some further details. The tbl_cards table is used to store bookings that can span everything from one to ten dates. Hence the `from` and `to` fields.

Now one of my customers have asked me to make a shopping cart for this, meaning that each user can make more than one booking in one transaction. I want to make this work by creating a `tbl_shoppingcart` where bookings are temporarily stored for 30 minutes or so, until the user are done and have completed payment.

However, this makes the excellent query above obsolete, because `calendar` now needs to compare against both `tbl_cards` and `tbl_shoppingcart` simultaneously, and make sure that the total number of confirmed bookings + cart bookings for any given date doesn't exceed 3 (or an arbitrary number defined by my customer).

I'm sure there will be a `UNION` involved, but I'm really not sure where to put it since the `HAVING COUNT` clause should span both tables.

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f1c9/1) supplied by @amdixon.

Answer (score 0):

After twisting my head for about 24 hours, I was able to derive the right query from a similar post (however lot less complicated query) here at Stack Overflow:

```
select @index := @index + 1 as `Index`, `Date`
from
(
  select date_format(calendar.dy, '%Y-%m-%d') as `Date`
  from
  (
    select date_add(date('2015-10-01'), interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day) as dy
    from digits a2
    cross join digits a1
    cross join digits a0
    where date_add('2015-10-01', interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day) <= date('2015-12-31')
    order by date_add('2015-10-01', interval (a2.digit * 100) + (a1.digit * 10) + a0.digit day)
  ) calendar
  inner join
  (
    SELECT `ID`, `from`, `to` FROM `tbl_cards`
    UNION
    SELECT `ID`, `from`, `to` FROM `tbl_shoppingcart`
  ) t
  on calendar.dy between t.`from` and t.`to`
  group by calendar.dy
  having count(calendar.dy) = 3
) dts
cross join ( select @index := -1 ) params
;
```

Obviously I didn't know enough about derived tables and subqueries, otherwise this would have been an easy customization. Seems like I've learned something new today as well :)